# Eclipse errors 'The package java.util is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.base' after migrating from Java 8 to Java 20

Tags: java, eclipse, java-module

I have a fully functional spring boot app currently on springboot 2.7.10 and java8. There are not a lot of dependencies, but one is from legacy code using java8. I tried to upgrade the app from springboot 2.7.10 to 3.0.6 and from java 8 to java 17 (using openjdk 20).

After renaming several imports from javax to jakarta and changing some config in spring-security, everything seemed to be working. I am even able to start the app using `mvn spring-boot:run`, but eclipse/spring-tool-suite gets mad with every **java.util** dependency I use, such as `java.util.ArrayList` or `java.util.Set`

I'm getting the following error:

`The package java.util is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.base`

Tried to remove the legacy dependency and got rid of all those errors, so I was suspecting that may be the issue. But the app happens to run ok if the dependency is added and using `mvn spring-boot:run`, so I'm wondering there might be something I am missing on the Eclipse config (or maybe on the POM) to make it run correctly.